# How to add cloudControl To my Domain

Tags: cloudcontrol

Currently I push my website on cloudcontrol.com as free account. It works well now. 
Ex: myname.cloudcontrolled.com

And I have got a Domain: myname.com

How can add my domain to cloudcontrol.com ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked [cloudControl documentation](https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Add-on%20Documentation/Deployment/Alias)? You have basically 4 steps you need to execute:

- Get verification code:
  `cctrlapp myname/default alias myname.cloudcontrolled.com`
- Add verification code as a TXT record to your root domain
- Add a CNAME pointing to the myname.cloudcontrolled.com
- Add alias:
  `cctrlapp myname/default alias.add myname.com`

Comment: Thank you! I read this doc but did not how to do :). By support from Host sevice assitance, I could add alias.

Comment: At which step are you stuck?

Comment: I did not how to set up TXT record and CNAME in ipage.com.
I asked ipage's supporter, they taught me to solve this problem.Thanks.